# Does Sharepoint have the option to digitally sign a document to prove its been read?

Tags: sharepoint, office365

In our organisation we need to share health and safety and various policy documents. Problem is people don't read them or say that they never received them etc.. I would like to create a document folder in SharePoint containing all our companies policies but I would also like for the documents to have a function that requires for it to be signed (or something similar) just so that I can tell who has:

1. Opened the file
2. That they have actually scrolled through the file.

If not in SharePoint how else would this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Per my research, your requirements are not possible.
You could check site usage or site collection usage. But the username is not displayed.
[Columns choose in SharePoint report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jSgN.png)

More information about [View usage data for your SharePoint site.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-usage-data-for-your-sharepoint-site-2fa8ddc2-c4b3-4268-8d26-a772dc55779e)